# How to Post Youtube Comment with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, youtube

I am trying to post a Youtube comment with Selenium. The following is the gist of the code (the lines about logging into Google are omitted):

```
comment_url = "https://www.youtube.com/all_comments?v=LAr6oAKieHk"
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)

driver.get(comment_url)
assert "All comments" in driver.title

textbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("box")
textbox.click()
textbox.send_keys("My comment")
```

`textbox.click()` worked as expected and set the focus to the comment box. However, `textbox.send_keys("My comment")` doesn't input the text into the box, but somehow deviate the focus away.

Could anyone give any suggestion?

Comment: So are you trying to create a bot to spam youtube? Anyway, first thing to question is, you're not **logged in** in youtube so how can you post any comment?

Comment: @Anzel The login part is omitted.

Comment: so you need to mention it in your question don't you think?

Comment: If you look at the raw HTML, you'll see there's no input for your box element, just two spans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to click into the box to make it editable. Then, [switch to the appropriate `iframe`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.switch_to_frame) and [set the `innerHTML` attribute](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) of an underlying "textbox". You also have to use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) throughout the code since youtube is heavily using AJAX and there are asynchronous dynamic DOM updates happening on every action:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

comment = 'test'

box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "box")))
box.click()

frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="+1"]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@onclick]').click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@jsname="msEQQc"]/following-sibling::div//div[@g_editable="true"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML='%s';" % comment, element)
```

The complete code (including the authentication):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fsignin%3Fhl%3Den%26feature%3Dcomment%26app%3Ddesktop%26next%3D%252Fall_comments%253Fv%253DLAr6oAKieHk%26action_handle_signin%3Dtrue&uilel=3&service=youtube&passive=true&hl=en')

# log in
driver.find_element_by_id('Email').send_keys('username')
driver.find_element_by_id('Passwd').send_keys('password')
driver.find_element_by_id('signIn').click()

# post a comment
comment = "test"

box = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "box")))
box.click()

frame = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//iframe[@title="+1"]')))
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@onclick]').click()

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@jsname="msEQQc"]/following-sibling::div//div[@g_editable="true"]')))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerHTML='%s';" % comment, element)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I tried to reproduce it, the last `textbox.send_keys` line resulted in an exception *ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with* Do you have any idea about what the cause might be?

Comment: @chenaren phew, that was kind of a challenging task :) Please see the updated code - works for me.